# POST Email Using Web API not reflecting "sender" and "torecipients" data

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

I want to create Email using MS Dynamics Web API.

Here I am posting data

```js
{
  "sender": "test@test.com",
  "torecipients": "test2@test.com",
  "subject": "Test Subject New 1234567",
  "description": "Test Description New 1234567"
}
```

But **sender** and **torecipients** are not reflecting in Dynamics CRM.
Only **subject** & **description** are displaying.

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 3):

You have to populate collection valued navigation property `email_activity_parties` for filling up `From` & `To` fields. `sender` & `torecipients` are fields just for reporting purpose with emailaddress of those activity parties.

```
    var email = {};
    email["subject"] = "Email demo from Web API";
    email["description"] = "This a web api test";
    email["regardingobjectid_contact@odata.bind"] = "/contacts(C41CE33F-D0A0-E611-811E-5065F38C8781)";

    //activityparty collection
    var activityparties = [];
    //from party
    var from = {};
    from["partyid_systemuser@odata.bind"] = "/systemusers(8D23B2C1-9869-4C3F-9A80-BA51375C1784)";
    from["participationtypemask"] = 1;

    //to party
    var to = {};
    to["partyid_contact@odata.bind"] = "/contacts(C41CE33F-D0A0-E611-811E-5065F38C8781)";
    to["participationtypemask"] = 2;

    activityparties.push(to);
    activityparties.push(from);

    //set to and from to email
    email["email_activity_parties"] = activityparties;
```

[Read more](http://himbap.com/blog/?p=2557)

**Edit**:

JSON will look like this:

```
{
  "subject": "Test Subject New 1234567",
  "description": "Test Description New 1234567",
  "regardingobjectid_contact@odata.bind": "/contacts(<GUID>)",
  "email_activity_parties": [
    {
      "partyid_contact@odata.bind": "/contacts(<GUID>)",
      "participationtypemask": 2
    },
    {
      "partyid_systemuser@odata.bind": "/systemusers(<GUID>)",
      "participationtypemask": 1
    }
  ]
}
```